# Two_body_problem: scipy.integrate.RK45 gives broadcasting error and scipy.integrate.LSODA never enters the twoBody function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, ode, runge-kutta

I'm working on a trajectory calculator for the Two Body Problem, and I'm attempting to use Scipy's [RK45](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html) or [LSODA](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.LSODA.html) to solve the ODE and return the trajectory. (Please suggest another method if you think there's a better/easier way to do this)

I'm using the Spyder IDE with Anaconda. Scipy version 1.1.0

THE PROBLEMS:

RK45: 
When using [RK45](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html), the first step seems to work. When stepping through the code in the debugger, twoBody() is entered, and works exactly as expected the first run through. However, after the first `return ydot`, things start to go wrong. With a breakpoint at the line `ydot[0] = y[3]`, we start to see the problem. The array `y` (which I expected to be 6x1) is now a 6x6 array. When attempting to evaluate this line, numpy returns the error 
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape (1)`. Is there an error in my code that would cause `y` to go from 6x1 to 6x6? Below is the array y right before the broadcasting error is returned.

```
y = 
 -5.61494e+06   -2.01406e+06    2.47104e+06     -683.979    571.469  1236.76
-5.61492e+06    -2.01404e+06    2.47106e+06     -663.568    591.88   1257.17
-5.6149e+06     -2.01403e+06    2.47107e+06     -652.751    602.697  1267.99
-5.61492e+06    -2.01405e+06    2.47105e+06     -672.901    582.547  1247.84
-5.61492e+06    -2.01405e+06    2.47105e+06     -672.988    582.46   1247.75
-5.61492e+06    -2.01405e+06    2.47105e+06     -673.096    582.352  1247.64
```

Could my initial condition `Y0` be causing it to reach a step too small, and therefore error out?

LSODA:
I also tried to use the [LSODA](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.LSODA.html) solver. However, it never even enters the `twoBody()` function! A breakpoint inside at the top of `twoBody()` is never reached, and the program returns the runtime. I have no idea what's going on here. Guessing I set it up incorrectly.

EDIT:
The same occurs when using Scipy's [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp). All the other methods of integration return the broadcast error.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as ode
from time import time
startTime = time()

def twoBody(t, y):
    """
    Two Body function returns the derivative of the state space variables.
INPUTS: 
    --- t ---
        A scalar time value. 

    --- y ---
        A 6x1 array of the state space of a particle in 3D space  
OUTPUTS:
    --- ydot ---
        The derivative of y for the two-body problem

"""
    mu = 3.986004418 * 10**14

    r = np.sqrt(y[0]**2 + y[1]**2 + y[2]**2)

    ydot    = np.empty((6,1))
    ydot[:] = np.nan

    ydot[0] = y[3]             
    ydot[1] = y[4]             
    ydot[2] = y[5]             
    ydot[3] = (-mu/(r**3))*y[0]
    ydot[4] = (-mu/(r**3))*y[1]
    ydot[5] = (-mu/(r**3))*y[2]

    return ydot


# In m and m/s
# first three are the (x, y, z) position
# second three are the velocities in those same directions respectively
Y0 = np.array([-5614924.5443320004,
               -2014046.755686,
               2471050.0114869997,
               -673.03650300000004,
               582.41158099999996,
               1247.7034980000001])

solution = ode.LSODA(twoBody, t0 = 0.0, y0 = Y0, t_bound = 351.0)
#solution = ode.RK45(twoBody, t0 = 0.0, y0 = Y0, t_bound = 351.0)

runTime = round(time() - startTime,6)
print('Program runtime was {} s'.format(runTime))
```

Comment: I'll take it out and see what happens

Comment: Having replaced it with np.zeros((6,1)), nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [`scipy.integrate.odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) for this kind of task which might be easier to set up:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint


def twoBody(y, t, mu):
    """
    Two Body function returns the derivative of the state space variables.
INPUTS:
    --- t ---
        A scalar time value.

    --- y ---
        A 6x1 array of the state space of a particle in 3D space
OUTPUTS:
    --- ydot ---
        The derivative of y for the two-body problem

"""

    r = np.sqrt(y[0]**2 + y[1]**2 + y[2]**2)

    ydot = np.empty((6,))

    ydot[0] = y[3]
    ydot[1] = y[4]
    ydot[2] = y[5]
    ydot[3] = (-mu/(r**3))*y[0]
    ydot[4] = (-mu/(r**3))*y[1]
    ydot[5] = (-mu/(r**3))*y[2]

    return ydot


# In m and m/s
# first three are the (x, y, z) position
# second three are the velocities in those same directions respectively
Y0 = np.array([-5614924.5443320004,
               -2014046.755686,
               2471050.0114869997,
               -673.03650300000004,
               582.41158099999996,
               1247.7034980000001])

mu = 3.986004418 * 10**14

solution = odeint(twoBody, Y0, np.linspace(0., 351., 100), args=(mu, ))
```

I cannot judge whether the output is correct, but it seems to integrate well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define `ydot` as matrix, that is, 2-dimensional array, even if the second dimension only has width `1`. The initial value is a simple array of length 6. By automatic conversion after the model of the idiosyncrasies of Matlab, `y0` gets interpreted as row vector, the (6,1) array as usual as column vector, the sum of both is a (6,6) matrix.

```
a = np.zeros((3,1))
b = np.array([1,2,3.0])
a+b
```

---

```
array([[1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 2., 3.]])
```

So in the next step you are trying to fill the entries of the (6,1) column vector `ydot` with the rows of the (6,6) matrix `y`, which gives the reported error.

Thus avoid mixing different vector types. Defining

```
ydot = np.empty((6,))
```

does this with a minimal change.

---

PS: It might not matter, but I would take the start time after the interpretation of the ODE function, directly before the solver call.